# What is the duration of a Toast LENGTH_LONG and LENGTH_SHORT

Tags: android, time, toast, duration, milliseconds

I need the exact duration of LENGTH_LONG and LENGTH_SHORT in milliseconds (ms). Also I need to know if the duration of Toast message with LENGTH_LONG will have the same duration in any phone and with any API version.

Does someone know where is the duration defined ?, I mean defined in ms . I know that LENGTH_LONG is some int const with value 1. But I could not find where is the actual duration defined.

Comment: did you tried to just specify milliseocnds in setDuration()?   Docs say it shall be user configurable,  but are not specific on this issue

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5079536/1993204). Like you mentioned `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` are not in ms but 0 or 1.

The actual durations are:

```
private static final int LONG_DELAY = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
private static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds
```

Answer (score 16):

The `Toast.LENGTH_SHORT` and `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` are just flags.
You can find here the official [android source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java) where these **flags** are defined:

```
public class NotificationManagerService extends SystemService {

    static final int LONG_DELAY = PhoneWindowManager.TOAST_WINDOW_TIMEOUT;
    /** Amount of time (in milliseconds) a toast window can be shown. */
    //public static final int TOAST_WINDOW_TIMEOUT = 3500; // 3.5 seconds
    static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds

    private void scheduleDurationReachedLocked(ToastRecord r)
    {
       mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(r);
       Message m = Message.obtain(mHandler, MESSAGE_DURATION_REACHED, r);
       int delay = r.duration == Toast.LENGTH_LONG ? LONG_DELAY : SHORT_DELAY;
       //....
       mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(m, delay);
     }
}
```

Comment: **Now, it is changed to:**
`static final int LONG_DELAY = PhoneWindowManager.TOAST_WINDOW_TIMEOUT;
static final int SHORT_DELAY = 2000; // 2 seconds still the same`

Answer (score 8):

its true that we are not allowed to change the duration of the Toast. But if you are searching for an alternative and you really need to do this with a Toast, then you can try this.

**Keep another duplicate toast in the next line**

Ex:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello StackOverFlow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Toast.makeText(this, "Hello StackOverFlow", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The user won't detect any change in transitions between 2 toasts.

Thanks.

Comment: Since it is clearly mentioned as 'impossible to do' in the previous replies I'm providing an alternative method and I clearly mentioned it as well. Hope you can understand.

I just searched now and found out same kind of question was there and go through the answers some of them are alternatives. But I don't find any down votes for them. Better for find alternatives than being said impossible only right? Hope this make sense. 
[Can an Android Toast be longer than “Toast.LENGTH_LONG”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220560/can-an-android-toast-be-longer-than-toast-length-long)

Answer (score 5):

You need set the duration override, with `setDuration` in the action, example:

```
int s = 6000; // milisegundo    
Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "This is my Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setDuration(s)
.show();
```

Answer (score 3):

I am wondering that why do you not use method setDuration() supported in Toast.java class???

```
 /**
 * Set how long to show the view for.
 * @see #LENGTH_SHORT
 * @see #LENGTH_LONG
 */
public void setDuration(@Duration int duration) {
    mDuration = duration;
}
```

Comment: You can only assign an int value: LENGTH_SHORT, or LENGTH_LONG.

Answer (score 2):

### `LENGTH_SHORT` & `LENGTH_LONG` are mapped to time interval of
**1 Second (1000mS)** & **5 Seconds (5000mS)** respectively,

To see this you need to dig into AOSP source code of Toast. in Toast class time interval is decided based on the FLAG

mParams.hideTimeoutMilliseconds = mDuration ==
Toast.LENGTH_LONG ? LONG_DURATION_TIMEOUT : SHORT_DURATION_TIMEOUT;

where

```
  static final long SHORT_DURATION_TIMEOUT = 5000;
  static final long LONG_DURATION_TIMEOUT = 1000;
```

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/f4bed684c939b0f8809ef404b8609fe4ef849263/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java

Answer (score 0):

Through *trial and error* I have found `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` lasts very close to *2500ms*