# Change the duration of an Windows Toast c#

Tags: c#, windows-10, console-application, toast

So I am sending a Toast from my Console Application with some information which works great, the only problem is that I need to make it slightly longer visisble. Is this somehow possible with c#, I only know that you can change it in the settings of windows. Also I want to have a diffrent duration for each toast.

> My code looks like this:

```
        XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(
        ToastTemplateType.ToastImageAndText02);

        XmlNodeList stringElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");
        stringElements[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(title));
        stringElements[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(message));

        String imagePath = "file:///" + image;
        XmlNodeList imageElements = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("image");
        imageElements[0].Attributes.GetNamedItem("src").NodeValue = imagePath;

        ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);

        toast.Activated += Toast_Activated;

        ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier(appId).Show(toast);
```

## Update #1

I found out that ToastNotification got a property named ExpirationTime, I just don't know how to use it since it takes a DateTimeOffset. Will it expire untill it is like 12 am when I set the DateTimeOffset to 12 am?
From my testings it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Expiration time is used to set how long the toast should remain in the action center.

If you would like your toast to display longer than 7 seconds, you can change the scenario property to 'reminder'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts

Answer (score 0):

To display the popup toast shorter or longer time, set this:

```
      var duration = "Default"; // "Long"     
      var toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
        ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", duration);
      //After, you can do:
      ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
```

In my PC, `"Default"` msg sticks for around 8 sec, and `"long"` for around 25 sec, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh779727(v=win.10)#sending_toast_notifications_from_desktop_apps).

PS: this is for the old Windows 8.1 RT tech; for the WinUI UWP go [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=appsdk).

Comment: [What is the duration of a Toast LENGTH_LONG and LENGTH_SHORT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965135/what-is-the-duration-of-a-toast-length-long-and-length-short),                                     and also [The term "toast notification" is being replaced with "app notification". These terms both refer to the same feature of Windows, but over time we will phase out the use of "toast notification" in the documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/adaptive-interactive-toasts?tabs=appsdk)

Comment: @Luuk, just found and  linked some info about duration.