# Wait until Toast Dialog disappears

Tags: android, toast

I was wondering if there was a way to display a Toast message, and then not execute any of the following code until after the Toast message had disappeared.

Comment: See this similar question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163563/is-it-possible-to-wait-until-a-toast-has-finished-to-resume-the-method][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6163563/is-it-possible-to-wait-until-a-toast-has-finished-to-resume-the-method

Comment: Saw those, but was hoping there was a better solution found since then, thanks though.

Comment: I like the idea on that thread of having an AlertDialog with no buttons that gets dismissed after a time.  You don't need to rely on Toast.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607410/finish-activity-after-toast-message-disappears seems to be the solution.

Comment: Yeah I know, I wanted to do this to more or less debug my code. Not essential for my program but was curious.

Comment: @Murat that is a bad solution, 1st because there is no guarantee that a toast will display exactly when you tell it to. If you do go with this a handler would be better suited. I would recommend writing your own toast class, its easy enough and you could get the exact functionality required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607410/finish-activity-after-toast-message-disappears